# Graylog - Alert condition based on repeated field

Tags: graylog2

do you know if it's possible to create an alert condition based on a message field? If yes, how can I do it?

A use case would be firing an alert if an user with id 123 is making more than 5 requests in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Graylog can do this on its own, but check out the Aggregates plugin.

https://github.com/cvtienhoven/graylog-plugin-aggregates